# Java Problems With Deserialization

Tags: java, file, io, deserialization

I know that this question has been addressed before,but i simply cannot find the answer no matter how hard i try.
I am trying to serialize and deserialize objects in Java. I am having problems in the deserialization. I do not get the values that were entered, but something along the lines of prueba.Estudiantes@1bd7848. Why do i get this instead of the actual values typed in?

Here is my code

```
package prueba;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("f.txt");
    List <Estudiantes> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean continuar = true;
    while (continuar == true){
    Estudiantes es = new Estudiantes();
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    es.nombre = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese Apellido");
    Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    es.apellido = kb1.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese Número");
    Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    es.numero = kb2.nextInt();
    lista.add(es);

    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);

    for (Estudiantes est: lista){
        output.writeObject(est);
    }
    output.close();
    fo.close();


    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
    ArrayList<Estudiantes> est2 = new ArrayList<Estudiantes>();
    try {
        while (true){
            Estudiantes s = (Estudiantes)input.readObject();
            est2.add(s);
        }
    }
    catch (EOFException ex){}
    for (Estudiantes s :est2){
        System.out.println(s);
    fi.close();
    input.close();
        }

    System.out.println("0 para salir; 1 para continuar");
    Scanner kb3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rev = kb3.nextInt();

    if (rev == 0){
        continuar = false;
        System.out.println("Hasta Luego");
    } 
    }
   }
 }
```

And here is my Estudiantes class

```
package prueba;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Estudiantes implements Serializable{
    String nombre, apellido;
    int numero;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you try to print your class when reading back the objects you previously wrote you have to implement the toString() method from the Object class here is what I mean.
Change your class to this:

```
public class Estudiantes implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123L; // has to be unique
    String nombre, apellido;
    int numero;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("first name: " + nombre);
        System.out.println("last name:  " + apellido);
        System.out.println(numero);
        return // a string you want to print
    }
}
```

Comment: everything should work now, your problem was that you were getting a hashed address of your object now since you override the toString method a System.out.println call on an object will call the toString() method in your class Estudiantes.

Comment: I get this error displayed in Netbeans "toString() in Estudiantes cannot override toString() in Object
  return type void is not compatible with String" in @Override

Comment: This implementation of `toString` is just sad ... :(

Answer (score 0):

> I do not get the values that were entered, but something along the lines of prueba.Estudiantes@1bd7848

That's what you get when you explicitly or implicitly call `toString()` on an object whose class hasn't overridden it.

It isn't evidence that you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are getting the values like prueba.Estudiantes@1bd7848 you are its already been deserialized. You just have to override the toString() properly to get the output. Not sure if this helps